# Set iframe Protection in Apache

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I am using the following

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors http://bmx-tv.net https://bmx-tv.net http://site.bmx-tv.top https://site.bmx-tv.top http://ps1.bmx-tv.top https://ps1.bmx-tv.top;"
```

on a blank .HTaccess page to try to prevent all sites besides those listed from being allowed to iframe my website but when i save the .htaccess it breaks my website with

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log

Any idea what im doing wrong? or how to only allow certain urls to iframe me? i need this fixed there stealing my content but i cant lock it down to only parent because i have other urls i want to iframe my own content on.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the : from? The [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) show no : and has the following example:

```
Header set MyHeader "%D %t"
```

Therefore it should be:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http://bmx-tv.net https://bmx-tv.net http://site.bmx-tv.top https://site.bmx-tv.top http://ps1.bmx-tv.top https://ps1.bmx-tv.top;"
```

[There is even a website which shows you how to enable and configure the Content-Security-Policy Header](https://content-security-policy.com/) for a lot of systems. Also Apache.

Comment: it still says Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @TimonthyWheeler Have you restarted Apache and enabled mod_headers?

Comment: restarted apache idk how to enabled mod_headers

Comment: @TimonthyWheeler `a2enmod headers` This is also something you can find easily in a search engine.

Comment: OMG mod_headers fixed it!

Comment: @TimonthyWheeler Congrats. Marking my answer would be nice too :D

Comment: the error is gone but its still letting people thats not on the allowed list iframe on there domains

Comment: @TimonthyWheeler Check, if the header is there. If not your configuration is still wrong. Maybe you didn't applied it to the correct domain or something like this.

Comment: like they cant embed ht,l but can php

Comment: @TimonthyWheeler What do you mean? PHP is a different story: https://www.projectseven.net/php-content-security-policy.php

Comment: its like some .html files its working on and some its not also?

Comment: okay i figured it out .htaccess on site.bmx seems to work but on ps1.bmx is does not enabled header on both and the same .htaccess file? but it works on one server and not the other